# How can I get frequency depending on time and sum of values at each time and id? I tried with aggregate function but I could not.

Tags: database-design, aggregate

I have data X as below. I tried with aggregate function but I could not.

X

```
   id    time    amount
        (month)
1   1      1      4
2   1      1      5
3   1      1      1
4   1      2      3
5   1      2      1
6   1      3      8
7   1      3      9
8   1      4      1
9   1      4      7
10  1      5      5
11  1      1      4
12  2      1      5
13  2      2      9
14  2      2      7
15  2      3     -1
16  2      3      3
17  2      4      8
```

With the below data, I  want to make new variables "freq", "monthly amount" and "max month". 
"freq" is the number of time at each month (e.g. id 1 has 3 frequencies 3 at 1st month and 2 frequencies at 2nd month and so on)
"sum_amount" is the sum of amount at each month (e.g. sum_amount of 1st month is 10(4+5+1) and so on).
"max_month" is the maximum month at each id (e.g. id 1 has 5(max month) id 2 has 4 and so one)
Thus I want to get summary result like this format each id, that is, want to summary data like below:

```
     id time  freq   sum_amount   max_month
             (month) 
1    1           3     10          5
1    2           2     4           5
     .
     .
     .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I'd present information quite that way. The column max_month is misleading when you join it to the other aggregates.

Let's make a table. (You should do this part yourself in the future. It lets us quickly paste working code into our own dbms, and everybody is working from the same data.)

```
create table test (
  id integer not null,
  time integer not null,
  amount integer not null
);

insert into test values
(1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 5), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 1),
(1, 3, 8), (1, 3, 9), (1, 4, 1), (1, 4, 7), (1, 5, 5),
(1, 1, 4), (2, 1, 5), (2, 2, 9), (2, 2, 7), (2, 3, -1),
(2, 3, 3), (2, 4, 8);
```

Excluding max_month, the query is straightforward.

```
select id, time, count(time) as freq, sum(amount) as sum_amount
from test
group by id, time
order by id, time;
```

```
id  time  freq  sum_amount
--
1   1     4     14
1   2     2      4
1   3     2     17
1   4     2      8
1   5     1      5
2   1     1      5
2   2     2     16
2   3     2      2
2   4     1      8
```

Now let's look at why you *shouldn't* include max_month.  First, a query that returns the right data, having the right meaning.

```
select id, max(time)
from test
group by id;
```

```
id  max
--
1   5
2   4
```

That table is easy to interpret. It means that id 1 had the maximum time of 5, and id 2 had the maximum time of 4. **Each row has something specific to say about one id**.

Now let's rewrite the output of the first query, and look at it.

```
id  time  freq  sum_amount  max_time
--
1   1     4     14          5
1   2     2      4          5
1   3     2     17          5
1   4     2      8          5
1   5     1      5          5
2   1     1      5          4
2   2     2     16          4
2   3     2      2          4
2   4     1      8          4
```

In this table, **each row has something specific to say about each combination of id and time**. (If this were a base table, the primary key would be {id, time}.) What does a max_time of 5 mean with respect to each combination of id and time? Nothing, really--its only meaning is really with respect to id alone. *But you can't tell that by looking at this table.*

So, really, don't do that. But this is how you *would* do that if you had to.

```
with max_times as (
  select id, max(time) max_time
  from test
  group by id
), other_aggregates as (
  select id, time, count(time) as freq, sum(amount) as sum_amount
  from test
  group by id, time
)
select t2.*, t1.max_time 
from max_times t1
inner join other_aggregates t2
on t1.id = t2.id
order by id, time;
```

But, seriously, don't do that. Don't.

Comment: It's ok to have a column be a function of non-key columns. It's not as _clear_. It might be _handier_. Eg for the info to be in one table. _No_ table can be read without knowing its meaning a priori. This one's is clear: its rows state the conjunction of what your tables' rows state. There's no need to only think of a row as stating about its key subrow or entity. It states; about the situation; via its values. (As do _absent_ rows.) (And if it states per key subrow/entity, it states per _superkey_ subrow/entity.) The **bold** / *italic* paragraph is unsupported.

Comment: *"It's ok to have a column be a function of non-key columns."* Sure, but this one's not a function of non-key columns. It's a function of different rows; it mixes two different levels of aggregation.

Comment: I was just trying to paraphrase your "something specific to say about each [key (?)]". So, it is a function of (some column(s) and) the table. That is also ok. Anything is ok. It's a query, not a base. Ok, a decomposition of one or more queries might be clearer. Many of your justifications for that and more (eg better) are specious. As is the objection in your comment. It "mixes": but that is just not a problem, theoreically or practically. Eg his query meaning is just "id [id] paid [freq] times in month [time] totalling $[sum_amount] and their last month in the year was [max_time]".